# qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) , Is this error means it is an affirmative QEMU error or maybe my code error

Tags: qemu

I use qemu-aarch64, and I run my c++ code ,but I met this error :

qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault)

It is sometimes happened.

I cannot to debug ,because gdb server lose connection when error happened ,then I can't get any backtraces.

I want to know is this error  maybe my code error or just qemu-aarch64 bug.

QEMU-aarch64 version is 5.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message can happen both when your guest has a bug that causes it to segfault, and also, more rarely, when QEMU itself has a bug that causes a segfault (either directly, or because it emulates something incorrectly or fails to emulate something and the result is that the guest segfaults).

In general, though, if you have a gdb connected to QEMU's gdbstub then the gdb ought to be told about the segfault before the process-under-debug is killed, so if that is not happening that's a bit odd.